# c++ Using the list container with custom class Objects, the list::sort function does not actually sort my data

Tags: c++, sorting

I have a list container of Node Objects, which has a defined comparison operaion (see header file)

Node.h

```
class Node{

private:

    int xCoord;
    int yCoord;
    int value;
    double fCost;
    double gCost;
    double hCost;
    Node* parent;

public:

    Node();
    Node(int x, int y, int value, int cost, Node* parent);
    void setParent(Node* parent);
    int getX();
    int getY();
    int getValue();
    double getHCost();
    double getFCost();
    double getGCost();
    Node* getParent();
    void setHCost(double hCost);
    bool operator < (Node& rhs)
    {
        return fCost < rhs.fCost;
    }

};
```

Now, i define my list as:

```
list<Node> openList;

    vector<Node> closedList;

    Node *start = initiateStart(map);
    //openList.push_front(*start);
    Node *end;

    Node *temp = new Node(1,2,8, 12, start);
    temp->setHCost(123.2);
    cout << "temp gcost : " << temp->getGCost() <<endl;
    cout << "temp hcost : " << temp->getHCost() <<endl;
    cout << "temp fcost : " << temp->getFCost() <<endl;

    openList.push_front(*temp);

    Node *temp2 = new Node(1,2,8, 23, start);
    temp2->setHCost(123.2);
    cout << "temp2 gcost : " << temp2->getGCost() <<endl;
    cout << "temp2 hcost : " << temp2->getHCost() <<endl;
    cout << "temp2 fcost : " << temp2->getFCost() <<endl;

    openList.push_front(*temp2);

    Node *temp3 = new Node(1,2,8, 1, start);
    temp3->setHCost(123.2);
    cout << "temp3 gcost : " << temp3->getGCost() <<endl;
    cout << "temp3 hcost : " << temp3->getHCost() <<endl;
    cout << "temp3 fcost : " << temp3->getFCost() <<endl;

    openList.push_front(*temp3);

    openList.sort();

    for (list<Node>::iterator iter = openList.begin(); iter != openList.end(); ++iter){

        cout << "iter Fcost : " << iter->getFCost() <<endl;

    }
    }
```

Now my program prints:

```
temp gcost : 12
temp hcost : 123.2
temp fcost : 135.2
temp2 gcost : 23
temp2 hcost : 123.2
temp2 fcost : 146.2
temp3 gcost : 1
temp3 hcost : 123.2
temp3 fcost : 124.2
iter Fcost : 124.2
iter Fcost : 146.2
iter Fcost : 135.2
```

But my expect result is:

```
temp gcost : 12
    temp hcost : 123.2
    temp fcost : 135.2
    temp2 gcost : 23
    temp2 hcost : 123.2
    temp2 fcost : 146.2
    temp3 gcost : 1
    temp3 hcost : 123.2
    temp3 fcost : 124.2
    iter Fcost : 124.2
    iter Fcost : 135.2
    iter Fcost : 146.2
```

From what i have read, should list::sort use the define operator to perform the sort? If so, why is it not sorting?

Cheers,
Chris.

Comment: Why are you using `new` to create objects, this is C++ not Java or C#

Comment: For starters, your example is leaking all the Node's constructed with new. Just create them on the stack. Also, operator< is best defined const and accepting a const ref. But I can't spot your sorting issue... Make sure your getFCost doesn't accidentally return one of the other costs ;)

Comment: you need to show how the `Node` constructor and `getFCost()` are defined, as it stands your question is impossible to answer because the problem is in code you haven't shown. Also, you should read about const correctness.

Comment: the fCost is define fine, i managed to get the sort working using a seperate struct which define the comparator ill post my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this by definig this:

```
typedef struct MyClassComparator {
    bool operator()(const Node& first, const Node& second) {

        //the comparison you want e.g. first fCost < second fCost etc

    }
};
```

Then hen sorting say:

openList.sort(MyClassComparator());

Comment: It makes no sense that this works but your `operator<` doesn't so there is a bug in some of the code you're not showing us

Answer (score 0):

std::list is looking for

```
bool operator < (const Node &lhs, const Node &rhs);
```

while you provide

```
bool operator < (Node &lhs, Node &rhs);
```

change signature to

```
bool operator < (const Node& rhs) const;
```

if you want to use in-class default operator. Or, your solution would work too (note that it has proper signature with const).

Comment: I agree the `operator<` should be const correct, but if that was the problem the code wouldn't even compile, it wouldn't compile and give the wrong answer.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, that's right, so, if it does compile, does it mean there is operator < with correct signature defined somewhere? Because, as posted it shouldn't even compile, so, if it does some operator is used, but it couldn't be the one provided since it has the wrong signature...

Comment: The code above compiles (if the missing parts are added). `std::list` will use that `operator<`, try it: http://ideone.com/xn3urG

Comment: @JonathanWakely, thanks a lot, this is interesting. I was expecting it not to since it is potentially dangerous due to possible side effects introduced by comparison if it is allowed to modify the members - as here http://ideone.com/Nwcsg7 . According to the standard, shouldn't std::list::sort resolve const correctness?

Comment: no, the standard does not require that implementations do `const_cast<const value_type&>(lhs) < const_cast<const value_type&>(rhs)` to _only_ accept const-correct operators. It might _allow_ implementations to do that, but doesn't require it.

Comment: So to be more accurate, a non-const `operator<` _might_ compile, depending on the implementation, but is not portable. The implementation can assume the comparison will not modify the object ([alg.sorting]p2)